# Two cards are drawn without replacement from a pack of $52$ cards. find the probability that the first is a $heart$ and second is $red$.

Tags: probability

> Two cards are drawn without replacement from a pack of 52 cards. find the probability that the first is a heart and second is red.

My solution goes as follows:
The number of ways of choosing a heart is $\binom{13}{1}$. So, the number of red cards remaining is $25$ as a heart card is already chosen . The number of ways of choosing a red is $\binom{25}{1}$. The number of ways of choosing two cards out of $52$ cards is $\binom{52}{2}$. So the total probabiblity is :$\frac{\binom{13}{1}\binom{25}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}}$

However the answer given is $\frac{25}{204}$. How is this possible? Where is the problem occuring. I am not getting it.

Comment: As other responses have indicated, in general, your Combinatorical approach to such Probability problems is good, and often best.  However, as indicated in the answer of Aaron Montgomery, the denominator and numerator must each be computed in a consistent manner.  Either you deem order relevant in both, or irrelevant in both.  For what it's worth, I normally choose whichever method is the most convenient (i.e. construing order as relevant, or construing it as irrelevant) for a particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your numerator and denominator are fundamentally different. Specifically, your numerator implies an order of the cards, but your denominator does not. Try changing your denominator to count the number of cards available to you on your first draw, then the number available on your second draw.

Answer (score 1):

Use the conditional probability rule. multiply P(first card heart) by P(second card red | first card heart). The first factor is clearly $1/4$. For the second conditional probability, the condition says the deck now has $51$ cards, $25$ of which are red, since one red is gone under the condition. So answer is $(1/4)\cdot(25/51)=25/204.$

Comment: Presumably $51$ instead of $61$...

Comment: @abiessu Thanks. will edit.